# Redirect with htaccess using first letter of "folder name" to specify php file to use

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z])([\w-]+)/?$ $1.php?var=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This redirects `/fH128` to `f.php?var=H128`. I would like to be able to have the first character, which identifies the file name, be uppercase, but then redirected to this filename in lowercase. Thus `/FH128` would redirect to `f.php?var=H128`.

I tried the following, but neither work:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z])([\w-]+)/?$ ${lowercase:$1}.php?var=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
RewriteRule ^([a-z])([\w-]+)/?$ {lowercase:$1}.php?var=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your Apache config files e.g. `httpd.conf` or virtual host config (but not `.htaccess`) define this `RewriteMap`:

```
RewriteMap lowercase int:tolower
```

Then inside `.htaccess` use your rule as:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z])([\w-]+)/?$ ${lowercase:$1}.php?var=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```